# Bounded waiting with semaphores

Tags: operating-system, semaphore, critical-section

what are the ways to implement semaphores with bounded waiting criteria?

I know that it can be made to follow bounded waiting criteria by maintaining the list of processes waiting on the semaphore as FIFO.
But, is there any other method which does this without imposing any constraint on the type of list being used?

Comment: In general, no.  IME, the thread containers for semaphores are FIFO queues.  I guess that, if you have the source, eg. for Linux, you could use another list class, if you want, for some reason, (?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you building any kind of complex producer-consumer class you wish, but it can be non-trivial:

1) Use a mutex to control access to the thread management data for both producer and consumer threads.

2) Inside the mutex, use whatever complex algorithms/containers/whatever to do - it's nice and safe in there.

3) If a thread then finds out that it cannot proceed for some reason, it should obtain a semaphore, store it in the management data, exit the mutex and wait on the semaphore.

4) If a thread needs to possibly release some resource that may allow another thread to run, it should enter the mutex, analyse the management data and, if it finds thread/s that can now be allowed to run, signal their semaphore before exiting the mutex.

Note that this is a generic soution to 'My Weird Thread Locking/Management Requirement Thingy'.  It covers madcademic wonderContainers, (you must use a variable-geometry, multi-level feedback superqueue as defined below.. ), crazed multiple-resource contraints, (thread AB24 can only run if it has 5 cars, three parking-bollards, two pink toothbrushes and an exploding suicide-belt), and all the other weird and wonderful things dreamed up by professors with a bottle of Tequila on a Friday afternoon.